# How to pull data correctly with Android SDK 2.0.2 (Incremental sync)

Tags: android, azure-mobile-services

We have integrated the new version of Android SDK 2.0.2 with Offline Incremental Sync in our project cause the new features are very helpfull for us, but we have problems with pull action.

More specifically, we get an unusual error (" E/SQLiteLog﹕ (1) too many SQL variables +++ LOG: malformed log message") from sqlite when the records to be pulled are more than 29. Could you tell us the changes we have to do in our code, to make the pull work correctly? 
Thank you!